# Axios "uncancel" api calls

Tags: reactjs, request, axios

I have a pages and inside have a `componentDidMount()`. We have API calls, however if you navigate away before those calls are resolved you get React error. You can't `setState` on an unmounted component. So for this reason I've used Axios `cancelToken` to cancel API calls in `componentWillUnmount()`. It's working and API calls are being cancelled.

However if you navigate away, and then come back to the same page, I'm seeing that those API calls are still cancelled and not being resolved. Maybe I've implemented `cancelToken` the wrong way or is there a way to "uncancel" those calls?

Here's codesandbox:
[axios cancelToken example](https://codesandbox.io/s/00l37w5jwv)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is creating a cancel token that is created in the scope of the file level. So, the first time it's generated and, after that, the request gets cancelled every time without making the request.

```
const signal = CancelToken.source();

class Roster extends React.Component {
   ...........
}
```

So removed the const `signal` which is declared before the class `Roster` and included in the constructor of `Roster` component.

I have modified the code for the `Roster` Component taken from your sample code, here:

```
import React from "react";
import axios, { CancelToken } from "axios";
import request from "./api";

class Roster extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      data: null,
      error: null
    };
    this.signal = CancelToken.source();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    request({ url: "google.com", method: "GET", cancelToken: this.signal })
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }))
      .catch(error => {
        if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
          this.setState({ error: "request cancelled" });
        }
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.signal.cancel();
  }

  render() {
    const { data, error } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>data: {data ? data : "no data"}</div>
        <div>error: {error ? error : "no error"}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Roster;
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit which parts in the code did you exactly change? this way it's clear for other users.

Comment: @c-chavez I have edited the answer, please check it.

Comment: it's perfect like this!